# How to extract the embedded attachment name from this email?

Tags: php, regex, email

My regex skill is... bad. I have this email body.

```
Hello World

[cid:image002.png@01C9DEDD.67C237D0]

Hello World

[cid:image002.png@01C9DEDD.67C237D0] [cid:image002.png@01C9DEDD.67C237D0]

Hello World
```

And what I need is an array of the filenames.

```
preg_match_all("/\[cid:(.*)\@/", $string, $matches);

echo "<pre>";
    print_r($matches);
echo "</pre>";
```

And I get the first filename fine. But not the 2nd and 3rd.

```
[0] => image002.png
[1] => image002.png@01C9DEDD.67C237D0] [cid:image002.png
```

How can I change this regex so it works for any embedded file in an email body?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can just change the expression to this:

```
"/\[cid:(.*?)\@/"
```

To make the match non-greedy.

Here are a couple of tools you can use to test your expressions:

- http://gskinner.com/RegExr/
- http://www.rexv.org/

Comment: Better, because more explicit: "/\[cid:[^\]@]*/"

Comment: Tomalak - it should be [^@] instead of [^\\] - there is no '\' in the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
preg_match_all("/\[cid:([^@]*)/", $string, $matches);
```

EDIT: Original post had a bug - apologies! I was trying to short circuit the greediness in an incorrect manner.

Comment: Oops - my mistake. Corrected version is in the edit update. Works now.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that if you have the whole email (headers and all) you will get more consistent results by extracting the filenames from the email headers rather than the body (the format of which is heavily dependent on the chain of mail software that the email passed through before it reached you).

Read up on MIME, multipart messages and the MIME headers to see how to do this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipart_message#MIME_headers

Comment: I have the email parser, what I want to do is create HTML with the a link to the physical image in the system.